# Find preceding and succeeding values for a time range in Sql Server for multiple ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Hello fellow programmers,

I have a sql query where I’m fetching data within a specific range, defined by **from**, **to** and an Identifier for a **single** measurement, **id**.
In addition to the values within the range, I also fetch 10 elements **preceding** this range, and 10 elements **succeeding** this range.

I do this by deploying the query in listing [1] and make use of my clustered index on **MEASUREMENT_ID**, **VALUEDATE**.

This works quite well for fetching values for a single measurementId, however I want to extend my approach to get values for multiple measurements at once, also with the additional preceding and succeeding elements.

Could anyone please give me a hint on how I might perform such a query.

Also I'm not too happy with performing multiple selects and combining them with **UNION ALL**, so please feel free to suggest any other way on how to best mount my query.

King Regards.

```
[1]
--element pre Range...
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TB_VALUES
    WHERE MEASUREMENT_ID = @ID 
    AND VALUEDATE < @DATE_FROM
    ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_ID, VALUEDATE DESC
) as pre 

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM TB_VALUES
    WHERE MEASUREMENT_ID = @ID 
    AND VALUEDATE >= @DATE_FROM
    AND VALUEDATE < @DATE_TO
) as main 

UNION ALL

--element post Range...
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TB_VALUES
    WHERE MEASUREMENT_ID = @ID 
    AND VALUEDATE >= @DATE_TO
    ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_ID, VALUEDATE
) as post 

ORDER BY MEASUREMENT_ID, VALUEDATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way using your current query would be to include a row_number() partitioned by Id and only select the top 10 that way for each Id.

```
select  *
from    (   select  *
                    , row_number() over (partition by MEASUREMENT_ID order by VALUEDATE desc) as rn
            from    TB_VALUES
            where   VALUEDATE < @DATE_FROM) as pre
where   rn <= 10
```

Do this for the succeeding query as well except order by valuedate asc. And remove your ID filters